# SwiftyJSON upgrading to Swift 2.0 requires to explicitly call .dictionary getter to access values?

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, swift2, swifty-json

In Xcode 6.4 I wrote a simple program in **Swif 1.2** 
by using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)
to parse an [HAR i.e: a JSON-formatted archival format for logging HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.har)  where everything worked great.

Updating to **Xcode 7** and **Swift 2.0** I also update the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) dependency 
, but this broke my program when it tries to access JSON values by a compact syntax like this:

```
let harVersion = mJSON["log"]["version"].string
```

In current update this syntax give the following runtime error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x1002bf218) to 'Swift.Int' (0x100869aa8).
```

I solved by changing/refactoring the code by adding .dictionary explicitly:

```
let harVersion = mJSON.dictionary!["log"]!.dictionary!["version"]!.string
```

I would like to know/understand in details the cause of this behavior and if there is a more elegant/robust/concise way to access JSON values. Any advice is appreciated.

Additional information:
**Podfile**

```
platform :osx, '10.11'
use_frameworks!

target 'prova-xcode7-swiftcli' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

Main.swift:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: mURL!)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?
var data: NSData? = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response) // , error: &error)
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    if data != nil {
        var mJSON = JSON(data: data!)
```

Comment: You are using cocoapods, are you using a GitHub branch? 

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON', :branch => 'master' `

The cocoapods version is/was outdated (you could try `pod update` )

Comment: pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

Comment: @GerritPost I realized my mistake interpreting watching variable while debugging and I found a way to fix my program ( I edit question accordingly ) but still I'd like to better understand what has happened and why I had to change the code in a more verbose syntax.